# Does a combobox require a child element with the role of textbox?

Tags: combobox, accessibility

I've got a combobox that is triggering an accessibility error from the Accessibility for Insights tool (https://accessibilityinsights.io/en/downloads/). The combobox can be seen in the mobile phone field with the country flag selector here - https://configure.awardsplatform.com

This is the error message I get from Accessibility for Insights:

[image: Image of error message]

Wai-aria 1.1 guidelines say the textbox is necessary - https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#combobox

However, I'm confused because Wai-aria 1.2 guidelines (still in development apparently) don't have it as a requirement - https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#combobox

And this example combobox also doesn't include the textbox - https://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/examples/combobox/combobox-select-only.html

There's conflicting information here so I'm unsure whether it's required or not. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer to "Does a combobox require a child element with the role of textbox?"

Under current (aria-1.1) standards: **yes**.

### Longer Answer

The standards will change soon(ish), you are looking at future guidance that has not yet been finalised. Under current guidance your country selection is using the incorrect role.

#### Why are you getting an error?

We are still working with aria-1.1 standards.

The [definition of a `combobox` in the aria 1.1 standards](https://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/examples/combobox/combobox-select-only.html) is:

> A composite widget containing a **single-line textbox** and another element, such as a listbox or grid, that can dynamically pop up to **help the user set the value of the textbox**.

As for [the example combobox you gave](https://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/examples/combobox/combobox-select-only.html), you may have been looking at an example intended for aria-1.2 (although I still don't believe it would be valid then as it should still set the value of some kind of input, but we will see when everything gets officially released as I think the 1.2 definition of an "input" still needs to be better defined)

For now a `combobox` is an `<input>` (or equivalent) with a related list that can be used to set the value of the `<input>`. A key feature is that you should still be able to **manually enter a value.**

#### What should you use instead?

For your example a `<select>` (or equivalent such as [`role="listbox"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#listbox)) would be far more appropriate as a user cannot manually enter a country.

Even when new guidance comes out [a listbox will probably still be a better choice from the definition currently in place](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#listbox).